# Is it possible to mount an external folder within Outlook and have it displayed like a mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to have a folder on my Outlook that connects to a folder on the network.  I don't want to  have a hyperlink to it from an email.  I don't want it part of a .pst or a public folder.  The folder has nothing to do with Exchange or Outlook.  It is a folder I use for other things but would like access to from within Outlook.

Is it possible to simply add a folder to the display where the mailboxes are?

Edit:
I just want to put things or access in it like any folder. I don't expect anything automatic or anything like that. I would like to put some attachment in it.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but what do plan to do with the folder? Are you expecting Outlook to treat the folder like Windows Explorer would?

Comment: I just want to put things or access in it like any folder.  I don't expect anything automatic or anything like that.  I would like to put some attachement in it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that detail.